# Jquery event is not being registered for new elements added by Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

#### Hi,

**EDIT :** As most of you suggested I tried with `.on()` rather than `.live()` .But It did not help.This problem is not only with ajax call, even try to add new element using jquery,events are not registered to newly created elements. 
*I changed my script below*.
 I am adding new table if click event is triggered on existed table.Click event is triggered well for first table but not for the next table which is added newly by script.
      I think the problem is with `.each()` . This function is not working for the newly added elements.Is there any way to handle this problem?

---

I have an html page where content is changed by ajax event. I want to register click event to all the tables that my page contains.First time it works fine but once the content is changed by ajax, the event is being triggered..
*HTML:*

```
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 </head>
<style>
 table{
  border-collapse:collapse;
 }
 table td{
  border:1px solid;
 }
</style>
 <body>
  <table clk="true">
   <thead>
        <tr>
         <td>S.No</td>
         <td>Name</td>
        </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr><td>1</td> <td>Rama Rao</td></tr>
     <tr><td>2</td> <td>Tom Cruise</td></tr>
     <tr><td>3</td> <td>Tom Honks</td></tr>
     <tr><td>4</td> <td>Will Smith</td></tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </body>
```

*Script:*

```
$('table').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('clk')=="true"){
       $(this).find('tbody tr td').live('click',function(){
         var str= $('table').html();
         str = '<table  clk="true">'+str+'</table>';
         $('table').after(str);
       });
     }
   });
```

**Note**: Event should be registered if the table has an attribute clk="true" only.To check that I think *"each"* loop is mandatory.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you run your script only once and them you change your DOM with ajax ? your script only affect what already exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `on()` instead of `live()`

Do you want something like this?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MWEMu/)

Comment: replacing .on() with .live() also works in your code. I agree on the fact that .live() should not be used anymore since it's been depricated but apparently it does not solve his problem

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `on` method while attaching event handlers for dynamically loaded elements. The `live` method is deprecated in the latest version of jQuery (if it hasn't, then it will be).

Example:

```
$(document).on('tbody td', 'click', function(){
    alert('hi');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`.live` doesn't work properly with `.find`. Try this instead:

```
$('table[slk=true] tbody td').live('click',function(){
    alert("Hi");
})
```

or even better,

```
$('table[slk=true]').delegate('tbody td', 'click', function(){
    alert("Hi");
});
```

And if new tables also get added, do it this way.

```
$(document).delegate('table[slk=true] tbody td', 'click', function(){
    alert("Hi");
});
```

Comment: "As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method" (http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Comment: @david it isn't depreciated, this is a topic of debate. I personally prefer .delegate because it is far less confusing to newer developers and works both in older versions and newer versions of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
$("table[clk='true']").on("click", "tbody td", function(){
    alert("Hi.."); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are using jQuery version 1.7.1, live method is deprecated. So, use below method. It'll work.

```
$('table').each(function(){
   if($(this).attr('clk')=="true"){
       var cells = $(this).find('td');
       $('body').on('click', cells, function(){
       alert('hi');
       });
   }
});
```

​

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you need to place your code **inside** the `$.ajax()` success callback:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'page.html',
    success: function(data) {
        $('table[clk=true] tbody tr td').on('click', function() {
            alert("Hi..");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the code to the AJAX response? After `if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)`, being `xmlhttp` an `XMLHttpRequest` object.

Comment: I did not get your point...Can you please explain it little more? **Have you tried adding the code to the AJAX response?** Which code you mean? and how to add it to Ajax response?

Comment: Well, you said you were using raw JavaScript AJAX, right? Could you post AJAX call? Anyways, it's a good idea to use the $.ajax() method; it's time saving.

Answer (score 0):

You need attach a delegate-event to the parent container of the element changed by ajax. Ex. if you ajax set the whole table you need attach the event on the body.

```
$('body').on('click', 'td', function(){ 
    // your function here
});
```

If you attach the delegate-event to an element reloaded by ajax it won't work.